# o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler : Duplicate step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Getting o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler : Duplicate step issue on running below spring batch code

Step 1
@Bean
public Step createPartnerRedemptionStepWithResponse(
ItemProcessor<Long, Aclass> partnerReProcessor,
String Job,
ItemStreamReader partnerItemReader,
String[] pattern) {
FlatFileItemWriter responseFileWriter = createResponseFlatFileWriter(pattern);
return stepBuilderFactory.get(Job)
.<Long, AbstractFulfillment>chunk(jobProperties.getStageChunkSize())
.reader(partnerItemReader)
.processor(partnerReProcessor)
.writer(createCompositeFileWriter(responseFileWriter))
.stream(responseFileWriter) // delegate writers must be explicitly registered as streams for the framework to handle them correctly
.listener(responseFileWriter)
.build();
}

Step 2

@Bean
public Step createPartnerRedemptionStepStatusResponse(
String Job,
ItemStreamReader partnerItemReader,
ItemWriter fulfillmentStatusWriter) {
return stepBuilderFactory.get(Job)
.<Long, MemberRe>chunk(jobProperties.getStageChunkSize())
.reader(partnerItemReader)
.processor(statusProcessor())
.writer(fulfillmentStatusWriter)
.build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamReader partnerItemReader(
}

Expected it to run the steps successfully